# android app periodically get fcm token without app launch

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

If a user has quit an android app and not relaunched it, is it possible for the app to periodically get the latest valid fcm token (and send it to a remote server) ?

Comment: I think you need to create a background service for that example work manager or service I think it helps you to achieve you requirements.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible for an Android app to periodically get the latest valid FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) token without the app being relaunched or active in the foreground. The FCM token is generated by the Firebase Messaging service and is tied to the app's package name and device.

Comment: "No, it is not possible ..." - but you have not shown why this is the case. " The FCM token is generated by the Firebase Messaging service... " - that may be correct but it does not explain why the first sentence is true.